# charge transfer between layers of graphite with stacking fault

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry

As a general rule, we only expect two parts of a system to have the exact same amount of charge if they are symmetry-related to each other. How much charge transfer would occur in graphite with a stacking fault (e.g., with stacking ABABABCBCBC...), due to the layers no longer being all symmetry-equivalent as in pure Bernal graphite?

Comment: Well, that's interesting point, but I wouldn't expect much CT.